# dead kernel when doing feature engineering?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, feature-engineering

I am working on a prediction problem. In my training set, I have around 8,700 samples and around 1,000 features. I used different models but still, it is highly biased. So, I decided to add new features to the model. I added some lags to the features and then used the polynomial tools in sklearn to generate polynomial features (degree=2).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
X = pd.DataFrame(X_poly, columns=poly.get_feature_names_out(), index=X.index)
```

Now, I have around 490,000 features. Next, when I want to do the feature scaling,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

I face an error in jupyternotebook saying "dead kernel" and I cannot go further.

[image]

What should I do? Any suggestion?

Comment: You could first try to run the lines in the last cell separetely to make sure the problem is with the ```X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)``` line.

Comment: all the lines work properly until it reaches `X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)` line. It takes some time and then the kernel restarts.

Comment: It is possible that your mamory runs out of space to perform calculations. To make sure, you can run the cell and keep track of the memory usage in the task manager.

Comment: I monitored the memory, it reached 98% an almost stayed there, and after some time, the kernel restarted.

Comment: see if this link is helpful: [partial_fit](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.partial_fit)

Comment: you can also scale your data with numpy. You just need to code the formula for it which is easy.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using sklearn for scaling, I should use NumPy and write the code, am I right?

Comment: yes that could be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### You need to do a batch processing with `partial fit` and then `transform` (also needs a loop):

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

n = X.shape[0]  # rows
batch_size = 1000  
i = 0 

while i < n:
    partial_size = min(batch_size, n - i)  
    partial_x = X[i:i + partial_size]
    scaler.partial_fit(partial_x)
    i += partial_size
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it needs a few modifications. The initial value of the index should be `index=0` and `n` should be columns and not rows: `X.shape[1]`. Am I right?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, updated it now :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no difference in `X` before and after running this code. I don't find any standardization.

Comment: why should n be columns? the idea is to divide the dataset into smaller parts so that a partial fit is possible on a single scaler. If you divide by columns you have have multiple scalers for each part of columns.

Comment: yes, you are right, I made a mistake, thanks for your clarification. I run the code, but `X` is not scaled. Do you know why is that?

Comment: you have to call `transform` after this, as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I used `scaler.transform(X)` to transform it, but again the kernel restarted.

Comment: Off course the data is too big to fit in the memory, please read the solution properly. So use batch processing here too... i.e., transform partly then train, discard, transform next batch, train, discard ... and so on

Comment: I deeply appreciate your help. I am new to it. Could you please refer me to a link or a GitHub page where they used this method? Thanks in advance for your help.